# Controlling mat-tab item position in angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to reach the following result with the angular material tab component: [image: result]

What I've tried so far without success is using flex property with margin-left: auto which should push specific item all the way right.

Adding here my code:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Top 5"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="All Drivers"> Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab style="margin-left: auto" label="All Drivers"> Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

On the inspect tool I managed to achieved this using margin-left: auto but not in the CSS file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following CSS class in your **style.css** file:  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-controlling-mat-tab-item-position-in-angular)

```
.mat-tab-label:last-child {
  margin-left: auto; 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use ::ng-deep it depends on which version you are using.
(in Angular 8 this is depreciated)

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label:last-child {
  padding-left: calc(50%) !important; 
}
```